# What's the difference between locking and expiring a user account?

Tags: users

```
usermod -e 1 *username*
```

will have the effect of ***expiring*** a user account but

```
usermod - L *username*
```

will lock the said account.

Are there any specific differences between the two? In my opinion, either one of them should achieve the goal of locking out a user from authenticating their account. Why would we need an expiration mechanism when one could lock/or delete the account in question?

Comment: Imagine a system having many many users in a organization. Some of these users might be contractors who will stop working after a certain date. Rather than continuously keeping track of who's leaving when, you create an account for these contractors and set an expiration date, the date on which these contractors will stop working.

Comment: @GMaster that makes sense.

Comment: @GMaster Does "expiry" mean that the user files will also be removed with like what `userdel -r` would do ?

Comment: Expiration does not mean `userdel -r <username>`. The home directory and the account will **NOT** be removed from `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expiration mechanism is needed to expire the account in the future. Say like a service account that can be used for a week or so.

The locking mechanism works only for local password login, not with other login mechanisms like PAM or ssh key.

`man usermod` explicitly says if you want to disable an account, you also have to expire it, not just lock it. Therefore, `usermod -e 1 username` is the correct way to lock an account.

Comment: Could you please tell me if expiration means the equivalent of running `userdel -r <username>` meaning the home directory and the account will be removed from /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files?

Comment: Expiration does not mean `userdel -r <username>`. The home directory and the account will **NOT** be removed from `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` files.